# Replacing a git merge with another?

Tags: git

I have a branch with commits that look like this:

`A->B->C`

`A` and `B` are merges from other branches which have not yet been merged to `master`. `C` contains the relevant changes to this feature branch.

`C` is dependent on `A` and `B`. `A` just got changed dramatically. However, these changes do *not* effect the parts of the code `C` depends on. **I would like to replace the merge from `A` with a merge from the new `A`**.

In this case, the new changes are based on top of `A`'s old head. But I'd like to know how to do this in the case that new commits are not children of old ones.

Said another way, I constructed the branch by:

- Checking out `master`
- Merging `A`
- Merging `B`
- Making changes and committing them as `C`.

I could create the branch I want now by doing exactly those things again (with the updated `A`), but I'd like to be able to just replace the `A` merge without reconstructing the branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play a *trick* to try to avoid having to redo all the merges you have done (including A) but you will be rewriting history, there's no way to avoid it.

```
git checkout -b hack A # create a _hack_ branch where we will first get the _real_ contents of the new A, B and C
git merge new-A # merge "the new A" into hack
git merge B # merge B
git merge C # merge C
# this branch now has 3 commits that have _the contents_ of the _new_ A, B and C.... it's time to hack history to get this in
git commit-tree -p A~ -p the-new-A -m "The comment for the new A" hack~2^{tree} # create a replacement commit for A
# last command will print an ID, and we will use it in the next command
git commit-tree -p commit-id-from-previous-command -p B^2 -m "Comment for B" hack~^{tree} # create a replacement commit for B
# will print a commit id, will use it in next command
git commit-tree -p commit-id-from-previous-command -p C^2 -m "Comment for B" hack^{tree} # create a replacement commit for C
# again, we get a commit ID which should be the branch like what you wanted.
```

Do a git checkout, check the contents and also check its history (git log, gitk).... if you like it, then

```
git branch -f master the-commit-id # or no commit ID if you did a checkout of it
git checkout master
```

Of course, you have rewritten history which means that it has consequences so use with care.

Comment: Was hoping there'd be something simpler, but I learned about `commit-tree` here. Thanks :)

Comment: This is doable without much hassle... just needs a little of _thinking outside the box_ (knowing the tricks, of course).